# Plotting GAIA barycentric radial velocity data with python

Tags: data-analysis, python, gaia, astropy, radial-velocity

Does anybody know of a good tutorial on how to use python and astropy to generate plots of GAIA, RAVE or any other database of barycentric (heliocentric) radial velocity data of stars in our galaxy?

I'd like to generate various plots of the heliocentric velocities of stars in our galaxy, making different restrictions on distances from the sun, and I'd like to see what the data looks like with correction for the proper motion of the sun and without. Now, I know I could find plots done by others, but I really want to learn how to generate my own plots.

I'm pretty new to python, so please target answers accordingly...

(added later:) There's probably a simple astropy function that if you call it with the right variables, say, a certain slice of the sky in RA and Dec, and a certain distance range in kpc, it will spit back a list of all the stars in that region along with their radial velocities.  I just need to learn the name of that function and how to call it.

Comment: Any particular aspect of the data you're trying to learn more about ? The question is a little broad...

Comment: Yes, I'd like to generate various plots of the heliocentric velocities of stars in our galaxy, making different restrictions on distances from the sun.  I'd like to see what the data looks like with correction for the proper motion of the sun and without.  Now, I know I could find plots done by others, but I really want to learn how to generate my own plots.  I'm pretty new to python.

Comment: @ThomasBrennan I've moved your comment back into your post. Comments are considered temporary, and can be suddenly cleaned up from time to time, and some readers don't even stop to read the comments, so it's always best to reply to requests for clarification with an edit to your post if it makes sense. Feel free to adjust further, and welcome to Astronomy!

Comment: What is the astronomy question here?

Comment: @RobJeffries That it's specific about [*astropy*] - there's a tag for that.